# Corrupt jars downloaded by maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

I have installed Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 I am trying to execute a simple spark project using maven which is already present in eclipse. I have included following dependency in POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now, when I try to build the project, it downloads dependent jars but many of them are short in size like 2KB. What should I do so that, jars are correctly downloaded.

My settings.xml contains mirror:

```
<mirror>
    <id>internal-repository</id>
    <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Comment: Open those 2KB JAR files with a text editor. Most likely they contain the HTML answer of an HTTP request. If so, you can see an error message (very likely).

Comment: Additionally, the repository `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` is the default Maven repository. No need to _mirror_ that. Remove the `<mirror>` tag completely.

Comment: If you're downloading from behind a firewall or proxy it may change the content of your jars to prevent their execution. Check with your network administrator if you're in a company or university network.

Comment: thank you guys ...u were right the 2KB file actually contains HTML response saying the download is blocked as my company network proxy/firewall is not allowing it. Any alternative do we have to build a spark project other than maven ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing everything inside the maven libraries folder. This can be normally found in \Users\.m2\repository
It is a hidden folder.
After deleting the files, Maven will re-download the libraries and hopefully they will be correct

Comment: I followed the same but again the files downloaded are short as previous